# Customize Standard Relationship Map component Financial Service Cloud

Tags: lightning, administration, financialforce, financial-services-cloud

I need to customize Standard Relationship Map component to hide add relationship standard button in FSC for certain user. Here is screenshot below.

[image: Relation Map Financial Service Cloud]

Things I tried to achieve this:-

1. I  tried to edit the record page for this standard component but we can hide only it's related account & related contact .
2. I tried to tweak CRUD object permission for it related object like Account, Account-Account relationship object but no luck.
3. I checked standard permission set 'Financial Services Cloud Standard' for user to disable/hide this standard button but didn't find anything related to it.

So my question is can we customize this standard Relationship Map component to hide this add relationship button on household Account's record. if it is then any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide this standard button on household in FSC we need to change crud access for Contact object.